# Where can I get YUV444 & YUV422 raw Video sequences?

Tags: video, yuv

I need some YUV422 and YUV444 raw video sequences for testing ffmpeg encoding to these formats.  I have 420 sequences.

1. Is there any site where I can download some test sequences(Any Resolution QCIF,CIF,... will do)?
2. Is there any tool using which I can convert the YUV420 videos I have to YUV422 and YUV444 types?